# getting contact photo in imageview in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts

I'm using a cursurAdapter for the list view and this code is in the bindView:

```
        String number = getPhoneNumber(friendName, context);

        long contactID = getContactIDFromNumber(number, context);

        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactID);
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        contactImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

i know it works fine since i used the same code in another activity in the onCreate, and it shows the contact photo in an image view in a normal layout.
plus i saw it pulls the phone number and id in the logs.

but here in the cursuradapter it wont work for some reason its giving me a nullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
10-13 00:28:57.456 16320-16320/com.barados.myfriendsdebts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.barados.myfriendsdebts.MainActivity$DbCursorAdapter.bindView(MainActivity.java:537)
```

and shows me the line of the bitmap is null and i cant understand why.
can anyone tell me where the problem might be?

Comment: Can you log the bitmap size and also the contactImageView reference to make sure they are not null?

Comment: @iago it is definitely null as i mentioned, but now that i check i see that the first null comes from the **InputStream** if it helps, the number, ID , URI pulls fine , just input is null, so the `getContentResolver()` returns null, what does that mean?

Comment: just match the contact ID with the working code in another activity where it is working for you, i think the URI has changed or this particular contact doesnt have a photo.

Comment: @iago that shouldn't be the problem, it happens whether the contact has a photo or not, the other activity i mentioned is the contact info, when he has a photo it shows it, if not it's blank, here it's simply null, its not the contact id problem, it doesn't matter what id i set.

Comment: According to the documentation it will return null when there is no photo, so most probably your URI construction is having an error. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#openContactPhotoInputStream(android.content.ContentResolver, android.net.Uri)